# Whats wrong in this sql query? It throws error

Tags: sql, select

```
SELECT *
FROM ItemTable
WHERE item_link not in 'http://foo.com',  'http://bar.com'
```

It throws error..

Comment: The question might actually be spam, considering the original links in the question...

Comment: Even if not deliberate spam another highly localised trivial syntax error that would easily have been resolved by consulting the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

`in` requires parenthesis:

```
in (...)
```

Comment: @user2443095 if it solves your problem then accept this as answer

Comment: @RuiLima: It is up to the OP to accept an answer or not. Please don't push users to accept answers in the future.

Comment: @PSR: It is up to the OP to accept an answer or not. Please don't push users to accept answers in the future.

Comment: @juergend sir he is new user he may not know to accept the answer.So i said like that

Comment: @PSR: Well I don't think there is a need for that.

Comment: @juergend  i think points dont give any thing.But they provide the competitiveness

Comment: @PSR: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110645/172011)

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `()` after `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM ItemTable 
WHERE item_link not in ('value1', 'value2')
```